# how to get a panel to not paint on run time C#

Tags: c#, panels

I'm new to the c# programming language, and I seem to have gotten by pretty swell up until this.

How can I start my program without having one of my panels automatically run its paint method, I want for my panel to stay blank and wait for the users input, but instead its paint method keeps getting called on on start up.

Currently I have found that simply not adding the event until after the button is clicked works, but somehow I feel that isn't the "proper" way to go about this.

Comment: by stay blank I mean do nothing, the program uses a seed the user enter to generate a pattern, as it stands now it will run instantly with the "null" seed, what I want is for it to do nothing, and wait until it gets a user seed, then paint itself.

Comment: @user3213422: don't add controls to your panel until you are ready to display their contents. Or don't have those controls paint anything until they have user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing some of your existing code, but here's a few possibilities.

1. Create some class-level boolean variable called `didUserEnterInput` and set it to "false" initially. When the user enters input, set it to "true". In your paint event, just check the variable.

   ```
   private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
   {
       if (didUserEnterInput)
       {
           // generate pattern
       }
   }
   ```
2. You could just hide the panel initially. Set `Visible = false` (WinForms) or `Visibility = Collapsed` (WPF). When the user enters input wherever, change the visibility to display the panel.
3. If this is WinForms, you could just copy the code out of the `.designer.cs` file and into your code-behind, in a separate method named `CreatePanel()` or something. Then call that when you need it at runtime to actually display the panel.

Comment: doesnt paint already check a variable to see if it needs to paint, you could probably trick into thinking it already painted?

Comment: so far between #3 which is what I was doing before, and #2, those appear the most efficient manor to do it in, but as j_mcnally stated, there has to be a way to turn it off at the beginning, I'll continue hunting for a way to trick it, but for now your answer sums up the core of the issue effectively